# Node HTTPS - mac verify failure when reading passphrase from process.env

Tags: node.js, express, https

This is my code for enabling https on node express server.

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const https = require("https");
const fs = require('fs');
const crypto = require('crypto');

const passphrase = 'passphrase';

const options = {
  pfx: fs.readFileSync('./cert/test.pfx'),
  passphrase: passphrase,
  secureOptions: crypto.constants.SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1 
                | crypto.constants.SSL_OP_NO_SSLv2 
                | crypto.constants.SSL_OP_NO_SSLv3 
                | crypto.constants.SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1_2,
}

const port = process.env.PORT || 8083;
const app = express();
...
```

This works fine if i hardcode the passphrase, or if the passphrase is in a variable. But when i am trying to read it from process.env.PASSPHRASE, it gives me "**mac verify failure**".

I can see that the process.env variable is being set by logging it in the app.

I have tried setting the variable as follows:

```
SET PASSPHRASE=passphrase
SET PASSPHRASE='passphrase'
SET PASSPHRASE="passphrase"
```

and in code:

```
passphrase: process.env.PASSPHRASE
passphrase: process.env.PASSPHRASE || 'passphrase'
passphrase: process.env.PASSPHRASE.toString()
```

none of these work.

I am on a windows machine and i can see that the way i am setting environment variables seems to be correct, as i am also getting the PORT from process.env when running the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shortly after posting the question, I realized that it must be a fault in how i am setting the environment variable.

This was how i was setting the variable and running the app:

```
SET HTTPS_PASSPHRASE=passphrase && node server-prod.js
```

it seems all what was required was to remove the space before the &&

```
SET HTTPS_PASSPHRASE=passphrase&& node server-prod.js
```

the space was being considered a part of the value of the variable as well. I did not realize it sooner as the trailing space wasn't showing up in console.log